# Shifting values to clear null gaps in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I've got an array and I've got a method that allows the items in the array to be deleted. Therefore we could delete whatever is in index 5 of the array. Index 5 would then be left as null, causing a problem. I'm aiming to be able to shift all the values to the left and then deleting that spare space so it's the correct array size. Meaning we won't have any null values in the array.

My attempt :

```
  for (int j = 0; j< myArray.length; j++){
        if (myArray[j] == null){
            myArray[j] =MyArray[j+1];
            break;
        }
    }
```

This isn't working for obvious reasons. I know where I'm going wrong. I'm replacing the null value, with whatever the next value in the array is. So I'm given two values of the same in the array next to each other. This is obviously not what I want. But, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've been told I'm not looping through the array enough. Any suggestions/advice ?

thanks

Comment: i think you get an arrayindexoutofbounds exception when trying to change item myArray[myArray.length - 1]= Myarray[myarray.length]

Comment: You can't change the size of an array, period.  You need to create a new array altogether and copy all the elements from the old array over if you want it to be a different size.

Comment: Consider replacing `array` with `ArrayList`, I think it fits much better - no need to do these shifts after removal, out-of-the-box `remove()` method.

Comment: try `if (myArray[j] == null) { myArray[j] = -1; }` put a default value.

Comment: If you used a `List`, you could do `myList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));`

Answer (score 1):

First, count the number of non-null elements in the array:

```
int numOfElements = 0;
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    if (myArray[i] != null)
        numOfElements++;
```

Then, allocate a new (possibly smaller) array:

```
Type[] myNewArray = new Type[numOfElements];
// Replace 'Type' with the type of your array
```

Finally, copy all the non-null elements into the new array:

```
for (int i=0,j=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
    if (myArray[i] != null)
        myNewArray[j++] = myArray[i];
```

If necessary, then at this point you can set `myArray = myNewArray`.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution that comes to my mind is to first sweep the array, noting how many "null" empty slots there are.

Then you create a second array, with the length of the first array minus the number of the empty slots you've calculated in the first sweep.

Then it's just a matter of copying the non-null elements from the first array to the second array.

Something like this:

```
public <T> T[] trimArray(T[] array) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) continue;
        count++;
    }

    int j = 0;
    T[] newArray = new T[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == null) continue;
        newArray[j++] = array[i];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Running time is in O(N).

Note that there really is no other way than creating a new array if you want to "modify" the input array's size, as an array is fized in size.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int[] deleteMember (int index, int[] array) {
    int[] newArray;
    int length = array.length;
    if (index < length) {
        newArray = new int[length-1];
        int i=0;
        for (int j=0; j<length; j++) {
            if (j != index) {
                newArray[i] = array[j];
                ++i;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Illegal index; handle accordingly
        newArray = array;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
testArray  = deleteMember(1,testArray);   // testArray  = {1, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int iTo = 0:
for (int iFrom = 0; iFrom < myArray.length; ++iFrom) {
    if (myArray[iFrom] != null) {
        myArray[iTo] = myArray[iFrom];
        ++iTo;
    }
}
```

Followed by either

```
for (int i = iTo; i < myArray.length: ++i) {
    myArray[i] = null;
}
```

the same as

```
Arrays.fill(myArray, iTo, myArray.length, null);
```

or shorten the array

```
myArray = Arrays.copyOf(myCopy, iTo);
```

Comment: Can we use post increment `iTo++` and `iFrom++` instead of pre increment?

Comment: Yes, just a personal trait of mine; i++ yields the old i value and then increments i, which is more work in machine code than ++i, which just increments i, and yield the new value. In practice there is as here no difference.